# Invoicing program to increase productivity

Tags: invoicing

I am a freelance translator who has found himself losing a substantial amount of time to billing. My current method is to use Excel templates, which is very inefficient because I still have to tab around and basically create each one from scratch.

I'm looking for a solution that perhaps lets me create a profile for each company I do work for and presents a pre-made form which only requires a couple seconds to input all the relevant information. I work per word, not per hour, so I don't believe time management software will work.

**What software exists that will help me automate the process more and increase my working hours?**
Why is this a good choice? What should I look for when evaluating such software and why?

Comment: For *easiest* set-up what country do you need it to work for - or many. Different jurisdictions have different requirements ofc and different taxes and some accounting solutions are optimized for different regions.

Comment: Well they are scattered all over NA and Europe. However, the only feature I require is the ability to save the invoices locally, rather than have a program automatically e-mail them out. I'm US based so don't have to worry about VAT.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Freeagent](https://www.freeagent.com/tour/) which supports invoicing, expenses, project estimates and so on.

You can easily create a profile for each company with necessary details. You can also configure a charging rate (e.g. hourly), so you can pre-populate it on your invoices. For increased productivity you can also use a time tracking feature (with integration to time tracking softwares such as Basecamp).

It could be a bit expensive, but it may save some money in favor of having dedicated accountant.